# Making an animation of moving dots between sites

Tags: animations, tikz-pic

How can I make an animation from this picture with dots moving according to the arrows?
In the picture, there are two lattices. The lattice on the bottom is the result of the top lattice after moving the dots according to the arrows. I want to to create a movie of the top lattice showing the dots moving between sites. I know that I have to use

```
\usepackage{animate}
```

But I can't figure out how to complete this task.
Any other codes which show a similar task is also appreciated.

[image]

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 0pt,
    shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
    start chain = going right,
      box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, fill=#1,
                    minimum width=6mm, minimum height=9mm, outer sep=0pt,
                    node contents={},
                    on chain},
    box/.default = none,
    arrow/.style = {draw=blue!60!black, thick, shorten <>=1mm, 
                    out=90, in=90, looseness=3,
                    -{Straight Barb[bend]}},
    arbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt},
    crbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt,
                    node contents={\scriptsize\color{red}$\boldsymbol{\times}$}
                    },
        label distance = -3pt,
       sx/.style = {xshift=#1pt}
                            ]
    \node (n0) [box,dashed];
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,13}
        \ifnum\i<1
            \node (n\i) [box]
        \else
            \node (n\i) [box=gray!25]
        \fi;
    \node (n14) [box,dashed];
       
    \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n0)  -- + (-9mm,0mm);
    \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n14) -- + (+9mm,0mm);
    \fill[black!75]   ($(n2)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) circle (1mm) ($(n2)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm) (n5) circle (1mm)($(n3)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm) ($(n5)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm)
    ($(n6)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm) (n8) circle (1mm)  ($(n9)+(0.1,0)$) circle(1mm)circle (1mm) ($(n9)+(-0.1,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n9)+(-0.1,-0.2)$) circle(1mm)(n13)  circle (1mm) ($(n11)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n11)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
    \draw[arrow]    ([sx= 1] n0.north) to node[arbox] {} (n1.north);
    \draw[arrow]    ([sx= 1] n5.north) to node[arbox] {} (n6.north);
    \draw[arrow]    ([sx= 1] n9.north) to node[arbox] {} (n10.north);
    \draw[arrow]    ([sx= 1] n11.north) to node[arbox] {} (n12.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 0pt,
    shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
    start chain = going right,
      box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, fill=#1,
                    minimum width=6mm, minimum height=9mm, outer sep=0pt,
                    node contents={},
                    on chain},
    box/.default = none,
    arrow/.style = {draw=blue!60!black, thick, shorten <>=1mm, 
                    out=90, in=90, looseness=3,
                    -{Straight Barb[bend]}},
    arbox/.style = {inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt},
        label distance = -3pt,
       sx/.style = {xshift=#1pt}
                            ]
    \node (n0) [box,dashed];
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,13}
        \ifnum\i<1
            \node (n\i) [box]
        \else
            \node (n\i) [box=gray!25]
        \fi;
    \node (n14) [box,dashed];
     
        \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n0)  -- + (-9mm,0mm);
        \draw[ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm]  (n14) -- + (+9mm,0mm);
    \fill[black!75] (n1) circle (1mm) ($(n2)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm) circle (1mm) ($(n2)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n3)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm)  ($(n6)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm)    ($(n6)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm)    (n8) circle (1mm)   ($(n9)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n9)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n10)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm) 
    (n13)  circle (1mm) ($(n11)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm) circle(1mm)($(n12)+(0,0)$) circle(1mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{}
    \end{center}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,arrows.meta,bending}

\usepackage{animate} 

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={node distance=0pt,start chain=going right,label distance=-3pt},
shorten <>/.style={shorten <=#1,shorten >=#1},
box/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,fill=#1,minimum width=6mm,minimum height=9mm,outer sep=0pt,node contents={},on chain},
box/.default=none,
arrow/.style={draw=blue!60!black,thick,shorten <>=1mm,out=90,in=90,looseness=3,-{Straight Barb[bend]}},
arbox/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt},
crbox/.style={inner sep=0pt,node contents={\scriptsize\color{red}$\boldsymbol{\times}$}},
sx/.style={xshift=#1pt},
shdot/.style={ultra thick,dotted,shorten <=1mm}}

\def\drawnewbox{\node (n0) [box,dashed];
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,13}{%
\ifnum \i<1
\node (n\i) [box];
\else
\node (n\i) [box=gray!25];
\fi
}
\node (n14) [box,dashed];    
\draw[shdot]  (n0)  -- + (-9mm,0mm);
\draw[shdot]  (n14) -- + (+9mm,0mm);}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,
 begin={\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle]
\useasboundingbox (-1,-1)rectangle(9.5,1.2);
},
 end={  \end{tikzpicture}}]{3}
\drawnewbox

\foreach \d in {2,3,5,6,8,9,11,13}{%
\ifnum \d=2
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=9
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0.1,0)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(-0.1,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(-0.1,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=11
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\fill[black!75] (n\d) circle (1mm);
\fi\fi\fi
}
   
\foreach \a/\b in {0/1,5/6,9/10,11/12}{%      
\draw[arrow]    ([sx= 1] n\a.north) to node[arbox] {} (n\b.north);
}    
 %+++++++ 
\newframe
 %+++++++ 2
\drawnewbox

\foreach \d in {1,2,3,6,8,9,10,11,12,13}{%
\ifnum \d=2
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=6
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=9
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\fill[black!75] (n\d) circle (1mm);
\fi\fi\fi
}
 %+++++++ 
\newframe
 %+++++++ 3
\drawnewbox

\foreach \d in {1,2,3,6,8,9,10,11,12,13}{%
\ifnum \d=2
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=6
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=9
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\fill[black!75] (n\d) circle (1mm);
\fi\fi\fi
}
   
\foreach \a/\b in {2/3,6/7,11/12}{%      
\draw[arrow]    ([sx= 1] n\a.north) to node[arbox] {} (n\b.north);
}      
 %+++++++ 
\newframe
 %+++++++ 4
\drawnewbox

\foreach \d in {1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,12,13}{%
\ifnum \d=3
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=9
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\ifnum \d=12
\fill[black!75] ($(n\d)+(0,0.2)$) circle(1mm) ($(n\d)+(0,-0.2)$) circle(1mm);
\else
\fill[black!75] (n\d) circle (1mm);
\fi\fi\fi
}

\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]